# Jquery checkboxes inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have the current situation:

```
<div id="2">
    <div class="row">
       <input type="checkbox" name="itemCheckbox_1">
       <input type="checkbox" name="itemCheckbox_1">
       <button id="uncheckAllItem">
       <button id="checkAllItem">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="3">
    <div class="row">
       <input type="checkbox" name="itemCheckbox_1">
       <input type="checkbox" name="itemCheckbox_1">
       <button id="uncheckAllItem">
       <button id="checkAllItem">
    </div>
</div>
```

Each div with class row has 2 buttons select all and delete all. When I click on delete all button of the div with id 2, then all the checkboxes within this div must be unchecked. The same happens to the checkboxes of the div with id 3. Here is my code:

```
$('#uncheckAllItem').click(function() {
   $('#' + <?php echo $model->id ?> + ' input[name^=itemCheckBox]').attr('checked', false);
   return false;
});
```

The problem is that this code is unchecking/checking all the checkboxes both in div id 2 and div id 3. What's wrong with it?

Comment: IDs must be unique...

Comment: What value is `<?php echo $model->id ?>` returning?

Comment: Yes @Niffler say right think what that value returns? Did you played any jsfiddle for this question?

Comment: <?php echo $model->id ?> is returning 2 in the click function of the button of the div with id 2. 3 in the click function of the button of the div with id 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, like the other answers suggested, change the IDs to classes since IDs are supposed to be unique. Secondly, use [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) when setting a checkbox status rather than `attr()`.

There are also a few other things, like the `<button>` tag should be closed and have the attribute `type` set to `button`. Alternatively, you can use `<input type="button">`, I've included both in the fiddle to show they work the same.

```
<div id="2">
    <div class="row">
       <input type="checkbox" name="itemCheckbox_1">
       <input type="checkbox" name="itemCheckbox_1">
       <button type="button" class="uncheckAllItem">Uncheck</button>
       <button type="button" class="checkAllItem">Check</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$('.uncheckAllItem').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings(':checkbox').prop('checked',false);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hLen8xqd/

Comment: Hi thank you, the code is just a fake code. I didnt even have buttons, but two href. Anyway, now I changed the ids to classes, but still, if I have now 3 divs and I click on delete all on the first, only the checkboxes of the last div are unchecked.

Comment: Also, I didnt used :checkbox, because there is one checkbox that does not have to be changed.

Answer (score 2):

first of all button ids must be unique you can write class instead

```
<div id="2">
    <div class="row">
       <input type="checkbox" name="itemCheckbox_1">
       <input type="checkbox" name="itemCheckbox_1">
       <button class="uncheckAllItem">
       <button class="checkAllItem">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="3">
    <div class="row">
       <input type="checkbox" name="itemCheckbox_1">
       <input type="checkbox" name="itemCheckbox_1">
       <button class="uncheckAllItem">
       <button class="checkAllItem">
    </div>
</div>
```

you can write simple

```
$('.uncheckAllItem').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings(':checkbox').attr('checked',false);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Change th id of your buttons to classes.

```
<div id="2">
    <div class="row">
       <input type="checkbox" name="itemCheckbox_1">
       <input type="checkbox" name="itemCheckbox_1">
       <button class="uncheckAllItem">
       <button class="checkAllItem">
    </div>

</div>

<div id="3">
    <div class="row">
       <input type="checkbox" name="itemCheckbox_1">
       <input type="checkbox" name="itemCheckbox_1">
       <button class="uncheckAllItem">
       <button class="checkAllItem">

    </div>
```

Then in your script,

```
$('.uncheckAllItem').click(function() {
   $(this).siblings(':checkbox').attr('checked',false);
return false;    });
```

This will bind the event to class named uncheckAllItems and find the div to be deleted and the uncheck it.

Answer (score 2):

You have some errors. Elements have to close. Also as mention ID must be unique, use classes instead. I suggest as solution to use an attribute `check` `uncheck` in your buttons element and check/uncheck checkboxes likes:

```js
$(".row button").on("click", function() {
  $(this).parent().find(":checkbox").prop("checked", $(this).attr("value") == "check");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="2">
  <div class="row">
    <input type="checkbox" name="itemCheckbox_1" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="itemCheckbox_1" />
    <button class="uncheckAllItem" value="uncheck">uncheck all</button>
    <button class="checkAllItem" value="check">check all</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="3">
  <div class="row">
    <input type="checkbox" name="itemCheckbox_1" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="itemCheckbox_1" />
    <button class="uncheckAllItem" value="uncheck">uncheck all</button>
    <button class="checkAllItem" value="check">check all</button>
  </div>
</div>
```